# can not upload image using Django-CKEditor (Error 400)

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

when I want to upload an image in CKEditor, it gives me the Error "HTTP error occurred during file upload (error status: 400)."

please check the image below

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhHT3.png)

**inside urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    ....
    path('ckeditor/',include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
    ....
    )



if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**inside settings.py  ---> for CKEDITOR**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    ...,
    
    
]

#Ckeditor


CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = "pillow"

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH="uploads/"


CKEDITOR_CONFIGS={

     'myconfig':{
        'toolbar':"Custom",
    'toolbar_Custom':[

    ['Styles','Format','Font','FontSize','BidiLtr','BidiRtl'],
    ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','NumberedList', 'BulletedList','Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','Undo','Redo'],
    ['Link','Unlink','Anchor'],
    ['TextColor','BGColor'],
    ['Smilely','SpecialChar'],
    ['Source','Scayt','Maximize'],
    ['Table','Templates','Iframe','Image'],
    ],
    'height': 100,
    },

}
```

**in models.py**

```
 content = RichTextUploadingField(config_name='myconfig')
```

would you please help me with that

Answer (score 0):

to be able to upload images, try this

```
pip install django-ckeditor // or just make sure it is installed
```

in settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
],

// at the bottom of the file add

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = "pillow"
```

in main urls:

```
 path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
```

in your models.py

```
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField

body = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True) // body, image, or whatever name  you choose.
```

that should do it.

Comment: thanks, taha maatof for your answer. I checked it all as you mentioned, but it did not solve the issue

Comment: ok, maybe i missed something somewhere, here i used it for a project of mine: https://github.com/tahasama/T-Blogit, hope that helps